# How to exec a command installed with `npm` command in PHP using `exec()`?

Tags: php, node.js, npm

In PHP running on Ubuntu, I can run `exec('npm -v')` and the output is good, 
but I can't run `exec('gitbook xxxx')`.

gitbook is a npm package I installed by

```
npm install gitbook -g
```

I can run `gitbook xxxx` in the Ubuntu terminal, how can I run it from my PHP code?

Comment: try running `sudo -u www-data npm -g install gitbook` and see if that works

Comment: I've put the code and commands inside `backticks` so that it's clear which bits are the actual code and which bits are comments.
Also capitalized words like PHP.
Both to make it a little easier for the user to read.

It might help if you add the execution results when you actually run the code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you run php by nginx or apache (for example, visit url example.com/index.php), sometime you need to export the **PATH**

```
exec("export PATH=/usr/local/bin && gitbook build);
```

after I added export PATH, everything works fine.

Answer (score 1):

I tried once like this on UNIX-based OS:

You can run shell commands via the `exec()` function:

// make an php file to execute shell script

```
exec("node yourscript.js &", $output);
```

Well output here become array of each line of output along with process id. You can kill process by processid also.

```
exec("kill " . $processid);
```

This how I was did. Other then this you can use node supervisor. Hope it will help you. Try your also with node command.